# How to find missing numbers between 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am looking for a way to find missing numbers within a range. I have a beginning number column and a ending number column in the same table.

I am trying to get the skipped numbers. I can get the next skipped number, but don't know how to get a list of the numbers that were not in the range. I have a numbers table if that would be useful.

Here is my example:

```
doc_num_begin doc_num_end
------------- -----------
20000007      20000008
20000011      20000015
20000016      20000017
```

I'd like to get `20000009,20000010`. I have searched but not able to find out how to do this using beginning and ending columns.

Thanks

Comment: How many bigger can be missed numbers range?

Comment: The user would provide the range such as 20000007-20000100.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a numbers table, then this is pretty easy:

```
select n.num
from Numbers n left outer join
     RangeTable rt
     on n.number between rt.doc_num_begin and doc_num_end
where rt.doc_num_begin is null
```

This is doing a left outer join from the numbers to the range table, and then keeping the ones that don't match.

Although pretty easy to express, the performance will probably be rather poor due to the non-equijoin.  You may also want to put in conditions on the numbers table, so you don't start at 0, 1, . . ., when the ranges start at 20000007.  You would do this as:

```
select n.num
from Numbers n join
     (select MIN(doc_num_begin) as MinVal, MAX(doc_num_end) as MaxVal from RangeTable) const
     on n.number between const.MinVal and const.MaxVal left outer join
     RangeTable rt
     on n.number between rt.doc_num_begin and doc_num_end
where rt.doc_num_begin is null
```

Comment: The ranges in the table might start at a rather large point, not covered by the numbers table. But that should be easy to work around, by changing the join conditions in the second query like this: `on n.number between 0 and const.MaxVal - const.MinVal` and, the second condition, `on n.number between rt.doc_num_begin - const.MinVal and rt.doc_num_end - const.MinVal`. That would still require the difference between const.MinVal and const.MaxVal not to exceed the maximum number in the numbers table, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to find the missing ranges, you could use this query:

```
SELECT
  t1.doc_num_end + 1 as start_missing_range,
  MIN(t2.doc_num_begin) - 1 as end_missing_range
FROM
  your_table t1 INNER JOIN your_table t2
    ON t1.doc_num_end < t2.doc_num_begin
GROUP BY
  t1.doc_num_end
HAVING
  MIN(t2.doc_num_begin) - t1.doc_num_end > 1
```

**EDIT:** And this query could be used to expand a range:

```
SELECT num+start_missing_range
FROM
  (select 0 as num
   union all select 1 as num
   union all select 2 as num
   union all select 3 as num
   union all select 4 as num
   union all select 5 as num
   union all select 6 as num
   union all select 7 as num
   union all select 8 as num
   union all select 9 as num) numbers inner join
  (SELECT
    t1.doc_num_end + 1 as start_missing_range,
    MIN(t2.doc_num_begin) - 1 as end_missing_range
  FROM
    your_table t1 INNER JOIN your_table t2
      ON t1.doc_num_end < t2.doc_num_begin
  GROUP BY
    t1.doc_num_end
  HAVING
    MIN(t2.doc_num_begin) - t1.doc_num_end > 1) rg
  on end_missing_range-start_missing_range>=numbers.num
```

(it will work only if a range contains at maximum 10 numbers, it could be easily expanded to some more... of course, there will always be a limit, but at least you don't need a table with all of the numbers)

Comment: This can be further extended to use a numbers table to "unfold" the ranges.

Comment: @AndriyM i extended my answer a little, to unfold the ranges (limited to 10 numbers)

Comment: I agree that you could do without a permanent numbers table. Still, a numbers table can have many uses, and so persisting a set of numbers would likely be justified either way. Even if it was just one, but often called, query that needed it, you might still find it beneficial to use an *indexed* table of numbers. Anyway, your approach seemed to me worth an upvote even before your update, so, nice job! :)

Comment: @AndriyM yes, I agree with you that an indexed table of numbers is always useful, and it would fit perfectly here! thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use known sequence number in any table or sample database for this purpose to filter with this id.
Cross Joining this id, would extend the limit you seek.

```
SELECT i from (select (w2.WorkOrderID-1)+(w1.WorkOrderID-1)*10000 as i
from    AdventureWorks.Production.WorkOrder w1
cross join AdventureWorks.Production.WorkOrder w2
where w1.WorkOrderID<10000 and w2.WorkOrderID<10000) as MyNumbers
WHERE i BETWEEN @StartRange and @EndRange
and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable
WHERE i BETWEEN doc_num_begin doc_num_end)
```